# Find Stale NFS Files

Tags: files, nfs

I've been pondering about an efficient way to locate stale NFS files for a few days with out much success and was wondering if there are better approaches to the problem.

Problem:

every once in a while I'm unable to load my server URL due to stale NFS (diagnosed after the fact). Stale files are usually found using `ls -ltR /<mounted directory path> | grep "\?"`, but this usually takes some time (since it goes over all files in a given path).

To further clarify, the issue seen in specific files such as Java library file(s) rather than the whole mount.

Hence, my question in short, is there more efficient way than `ls -ltR | grep "\?"` to locate stale NFS files?

Thank you.

Edit:

To clarify, fixing the issue isn't intended to be in the scope of this question, since I've written a script to handle stale NFS situation (with `unmount/mount, lsof, kill -15`).

Comment: Are you talking about individual NFS file handles going stale, or the mounts themselves?

Comment: @Sobrique, certain files (such as in Java lib) go stale which prevents the server from working correctly.

Comment: OK, so what that means is - something's modified the file - either by moving it/renaming it/editing it - and something on your client is therefore out of sync. The real answer is to figure out what's doing that - NFS file handles 'going stale' is expected behaviour, to avoid data corruption.

Comment: @Sobrique assuming I can't fix the causing reason at this point (and leaving it as unknown). Is there a way to diagnose the issue faster than the above method?

Comment: `mount -o remount` will refresh the NFS handles on the mount. Doesn't 'detect' them per se, but will clear the problem.

Comment: @Sobrique , to clarify, I'm aware on how to fix the issue and have written bash script for it. My question scope is mainly to reduce diagnostic time.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer to fixing stale NFS file handles is doing `mount -o remount`. But ideally, instead you'll track down what's making the changes to the file system, as that's what's causing this in the first place.

Comment: fixing it is not in the scope of the question, since I've scripts to do that. I'd just like to save time in finding out if it's a stale NFS file issue or not.

Comment: In which case - no, I don't think there's a faster way, as you need to `stat` the file to detect the problem - your `ls` does that already. `find` might be slightly faster, but it's fundamentally got to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was afraid that'll be the answer.... :-(

Comment: The `open` syscall should be returning a different error code to normal - `ESTALE`. You _might_ be able to catch that happening, either within the app - or maybe by turning on auditing.

Comment: wouldn't this require exact file name? I'm not familiar with `open` syscall (just from what I've read after you posted your comment).

Comment: Yes - when you're 'opening' a file, the operation will generate an error. That won't do you much good unless whatever is reading the file is handling that properly (and it sounds like it isn't). However you _may_ find that you can turn on auditing, configure it to log `open` and then spot the error occurring in your audit logs.